# Merging search trees and finding elements in them

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory

I've got this problem in my theoretical homework on algorithms and data structures related to search trees:

Given *n* numbers *a*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *a*<sub>n</sub>, initially each in its own set. There are two types of queries:

1. unite two sets;
2. find the smallest element bigger than *x* in a specific set.

In these queries, set is specified by one of its elements' index in *{a<sub>i</sub>}*. The task is to process *q* queries in *O(n + q log(n))* time.

I've tried using AVL trees to store sets' elements, but this approach results in *O(n log(n))* or *O(n)* merge time, so the overall time complexity requirement is not satisfied. At the moment I have only these few ideas (but actually they don't quite help):

1. There are at most *n* unite queries.
2. If *q > n*, eventually, we'll need to build a search tree containing all *n* elements of *{a<sub>i</sub>}* to process the last *(q - n)* queries of type *(2)*. Thus, it seems to be reasonable to first solve the problem with *q ≤ n* and then naturally extend the solution to *q > n*.
3. To create a set containing *(k + 1)* elements at least *k* merge operations is needed (this is easy to prove by mathematical induction), so at each step of processing queries we need work with "not-so-big" sets only. This might yield some tight asymptotic estimates.
4. Probably there is a way to somehow scan several first queries before processing them, understand which sets are involved in type *(2)* queries, and merge them only, ignoring other unite requests.
5. There is no memory limit, so this might be abused in some way.

Comment: What do you mean by unite two sets?

Comment: It means to merge two sets from the initial family. For example, if n = 3, at the beginning we have three sets: {a1}, {a2}, {a3}, and after unite(1, 3) the new sets are {a1, a3}, {a2}. If the next query is smallestBigger(x = 10, set = 3), then we need to find the smallest element bigger than 10 in {a1, a3}.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your solution of using self-balancing binary search trees to represent the sets was correct, and your ideas (1) - (3) are essential to achieve a tighter asymptotic bound.

Setting up the sets initially is O(n), and searching (finding the smallest element larger than some *x*) within each set is O(log n), so q searches has a cost of O(q log n).

Now let's consider the merge operations. To merge two binary search trees of size a and b, insert all elements of the smaller tree into the larger tree. This can be done in `O(min(a,b)*log(max(a,b)+1))`.

But what is the complexity of q successive merge operations, if we start with singleton sets? We can prove by induction that for q < n, the cost is O(q log n). (As you have noted, there cannot be any more merge operations apart from merging a set with itself, which is a no-op.)

So the cost of q merge operations is the cost of q-1 merges plus the cost of the last merge. By the inductive hypothesis, the cost of q-1 merges is `O((q-1)log n)`.

The cost of the last merge is `O(min(a,b)*log(max(a,b)+1))`. But `a` and `b` are less than `q`, so for the last merge we get an upper bound of `O(q * log(q + 1))`. Since `q < n`, this is a subset of `O(q log n)`. So the total cost of q merge operations is `O((q-1) log n + q log n) = O(q log n)`.

Therefore, the total complexity is bounded by O(n + q log n).